# Unreal real engine 4.26 how to export into html5

Tags: html, unreal-engine4, export-to-html

Good day,

It seems that unreal engine 4.26 has officially taken out html5 exporting for games and was put as a plugin for the community but sadly it seems that the step by step guide from

https://github.com/UnrealEngineHTML5/Documentation/blob/master/Platforms/HTML5/HowTo/README.0.building.UE4.Editor.md#development-environment-requirements

isnt properly made and done and missing some steps.

is there another way for me to export my project as a web / html5 game in unreal engine 4.26v.

any info would be very helpful especially if the info is a tutorial video on how to do it , it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: How can you tell the guide "isnt properly made and done and missing some steps"? Are you stuck on some step in it? (How would you know a tutorial video would be any better?)

Comment: hi thank you for taking the time in helping me , in the documentation it said that i needed to  fetch the emsdk and build the 3rd party libraries for html5, i needed to cd into the folder engine but the platform was missing,   cd Engine/Platform/HTML5   . i double checked the whole project paths and subs but there doesnt seem to be any  Platform path hence why i wanted to ask, if there is any video tutorial so that i might be able to see what i am missing or have gotten wrong on the steps that i have made for the html5 exportation sadly, will be back later to try again later

Comment: Did you follow e.g. https://github.com/UnrealEngineHTML5/Documentation/blob/master/README.md so you have access to the HTML5-enabled fork of UE?